# Convert OleVariant to Object in Delphi

Tags: delphi, casting, delphi-6

I'm working on this project where we don't have the source code for large chunks of the project, but we have the .DLL files with some information.  There is a bug in the DLL files.  I am able to create a subclass of the class with the bug in it and I would like to downcast the object which already exists at a point I have access to it.  The issue is that at any point I have access to the object, it's cast as a Variant.  I've tried the following (edited to remove context):

```
tempSubclass := Subclass(ParentClass(Integer(oleVariantCast)));
```

but I get the following error:

```
Could not convert variant of type (Dispatch) into type (Integer)
```

Is there any other way to get the pointer to the object out of the OleVariant and/or do the typecasting involved?

Thank you.

EDIT: Yes, the Parentclass implements IDispatch.
CORRECTION: The parentclass implements an interface which inherits from IDispatch.

Comment: is your code compiled with the same version of delphi as the code in the dll?

Comment: As far as I know, it's all in Delphi 6.

Comment: you are going to want to be sure if you are trying to consume objects across module boundaries. I still can't quite follow what you are trying to do once you've extracted this object reference.

Comment: how do you subclass a Delphi object that already exists? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I created a subclass of the parent class and am downcasting the object to be of the subclasses type once I cast it back into a type of the parent class.

Comment: In order to do this you'll need to change the VMT pointer I guess.

Comment: I think if it was me I'd contemplate hooking the methods that needs to be fixed. That way you can reach static methods too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try type cast to IUnknown first.

```
tempSubclass := Subclass(ParentClass(Integer(IUnknown(oleVariantCast))));
```

Comment: This just screams "it compiles, but does it really work" at me.

Comment: @Warren P I tried to describe here how to go from OleVariant to Interface through IUnknown http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938601/getting-an-istream-from-an-olevariant/4938818#4938818 . If it works in this case or not I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

A Dispatch Variant is a pretty generic interface, not a class (which is why it can't be typecast to a Delphi object - it isn't one, and doesn't have the VMT for the class you're trying to cast it to become).

If the DLL contains a type library, you can import that into Delphi and then use the interfaces it contains directly without trying to cast them to anything else first.

If you have documentation about the actual interface implementation in the DLL, you can write a Delphi class that uses that interface. You can convert it by defining a type to represent the interface, and then get access to it using `as`:

```
type
  TYourInterface=interface(IDispatch)
    // the interface definition here
  end;

var
  Intf: TYourInterface;
begin
  Intf := YuorOleVariant as TYourInterface;
  // work with interface from DLL using Intf.
  Intf := nil;
end;
```

Comment: I tried what you seemed to be suggesting which is:  "tempSubclass := oleVariantCast as Subclass" and it gives an error saying "Operator not applicable to this operand type".

Comment: I misunderstood what you were saying, but I get the same error when I try it with an interface.